# Removing "[" from a column in pentaho using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pentaho, spoon

I have a column whose data type is number but there exist a non-integer value "["  I want to remove this using javascript in pentaho.I have tried this script.
can someone please help.

```
var abc = <column_name>.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: <column_name>.replace(/\\[/g,'');

Comment: ok, what's wrong with that?

Comment: `I have a column whose data type is number but there exist a non-integer value "[" `? wondering how? you mean a numbers list?

Comment: That'll throw syntax error. Add actual code.

Comment: no ,not a number list just may be a typos from user ,it's simply "[".

Comment: Are you sure that you column's data type is Number? Since I can't see how it can contain '[' character (at least if there is no format on the column), and I don't think you're allowed to use replace() method on Number columns (your JS step should fail in this case, writing some message to the log). And if your column is String, then your regExp should work, you'll just need to replace the value of your old field.

Comment: Yes it was string not number

Comment: From my point your expression should work for non-NULL values. Have you specified, that value of <column_name> should be replaced by value of abc variable? It is done in the "Fields" table in bottom of your JS step editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. But i have not tested yet.

```
  String str = "a12.334tyz.78x";
  str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: Expressing regular expressions with the `/.../` notation is usually better than the string equivalent for reasons of not having to escape backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

try using this `var abc = <column_name>.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')`
this will return you only string of numbers and than you can parse it to integer.